# Webpage child scrolling issue while using Webview inside SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, swiperefreshlayout

I have one `Webview` in my application and loading a web form inside it. I am also using `SwipeRefreshLayout` to reload the webpage.

I had one issue while scroll down web page and after some research, i have implemented below logic.

```
wv_content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        layout_swipe_refresh.setEnabled(wv_content.getScrollY() == 0);
    }
});
```

It's fixed. Working fine now.

**Issue:**

But right now i am getting one another issue for scrolling content. I have Dropdown in my web page.

So if i open Dropdown and scroll up then it's ok but while scroll down, SwipeRefreshLayout executed and page refreshing.

This is because i have integrated logic to check webView's y position and in this case webView's y position will be 0 every time and inner content scroll position will be different.

Comment: Did you resolved the issue ?

Comment: Yes we have resolved that issue from web page directly. No any changes in mobile app.

Comment: Can you tell me what changes you made into website, I'm facing same issue